# How to form mongoose query for $all in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given this collection:

```
    [{
        "users": [{
            "name": "one"

        }, {
            "name": "two"

        }]
    }, {
        "users": [{
            "name": "one"

        }, {
            "name": "three"

        }]
    }, {
        "users": [{
            "name": "fifteen"

        }, {
            "name": "one"

        }]
    }]
```

How can I query this using values (ie, `"one"` and `"two"`) so that the `findOne` method returns only the document that has **both** `"name":"one"`**and** `"name":"two"` (order not relevant)? The `users` array will always have 2 elements, no more, no less.

I was trying something along the lines of:

```
Collection.findOne({"users":{$all:["one", "two"]}})
```

But it isn't working. Can anyone help?

**EDIT:** Latest attempt:

```
Collection.findOne({"users":{"name": {$all:["one","two"]}}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
{"users": {$all: [{"name": "one"}, {"name": "two"}]}}
```

Or use dot notation as proposed by JohnnyHK.

See here how $all is used: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

EDIT: Data was changed.

Comment: thanks for the help, but actually I just noticed that my data wasn't correct and in fact, I don't actually have a `user` object. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using dot notation to identify a specific field within the array to which the `$all` operator should be applied:

```
Collection.findOne({'users.name': {$all: ['one', 'two']}})
```